# Trying to create a windows docker image from amazon ec2 ami image

Tags: docker, image, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I am trying to create a  windows docker image from the amazon ec2 ami image, in order to use it in aws codebuild, it have created a .tar and .tar.gz file from that ami image, after that, used docker import and docker load command, but it is not working in either of the case,

1. While using docker load command like below (./D.tar.gz is a file), getting below error.

```
docker import ./D.tar.gz
Error response from daemon: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: hcsshim::ProcessBaseLayer \\?\C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\674efbdca1c337c8088043431143d2e2ed6768c40709c82efcb64dd4c8efb898: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

2. while using docker import command, getting below

```
D:\>type D.tar.gz | docker import - exampleimagelocal:new
Error response from daemon: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: hcsshim::ProcessBaseLayer \\?\C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\854a13994506ba1814a32f64409acf91034def0480149bad1ab793df312537ef: The system cannot find the path specified.

D:\>type D.tar | docker import - exampleimagelocal:new
Error response from daemon: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: hcsshim::ProcessBaseLayer \\?\C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\e931e69f9fe8b5bd052d5e9821d7135a30610dc5ab93fd9f45e527588c4cbcc7: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

And I am using Windows Server 2016 with Containers AMI as docker host.

Please provide the solution or suggestion, is it possible, because in case of linux, I am able to do it.